# NodeJS on Remote Ubuntu 14.04 not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have a remote server running on Ubuntu 14.04. I have used express-generator to create a basic express APP.

The nodeJS is listening on port 8000. When I make a request using the http://ServerIP:8000 there is no response. 
The HTTP request is actually going through but does not seem to reach the nodejs process.

```
sudo tcpdump -vv -x -X -s 1500 -i interface1 'port 8000'

xx.xx.xx.xx > yy.yy.yy.yy.8000: Flags [S], cksum 0x18b7 (correct), seq 202090794, win 65535, options [mss 1400,sackOK,eol], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0030 772d 4000 3406 c4d6 6ad8 a9fb  E..0w-@.4...j...
    0x0010:  c0a8 3548 8c6b 1f40 0c0b a92a 0000 0000  ..5H.k.@...*....
    0x0020:  7002 ffff 18b7 0000 0204 0578 0402 0000  p..........x....
tt.tt.tt IP (tos 0x0, ttl 52, id 1450, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
     xx.xx.xx.xx > yy.yy.yy.yy.8000: Flags [S], cksum 0x00c3 (correct), seq 1654024850, win 65535, options [mss 1400,sackOK,eol], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0030 05aa 4000 3406 365a 6ad8 a9fb  E..0..@.4.6Zj...
    0x0010:  c0a8 3548 8c6c 1f40 6296 6a92 0000 0000  ..5H.l.@b.j.....
    0x0020:  7002 ffff 00c3 0000 0204 0578 0402 0000  p..........x....
```

Also

```
netstat -pan | grep 8000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2769/node
```

Any idea whats going wrong/what I'm missing ?

Comment: How are you running nodejs exactly?

Comment: `npm start`

Is this what you asked ? Otherwise I'm not able to understand your question

Comment: yes that's what I means. What does your start script look like? Can you try and produce an mcve? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Its the default script that you get with expressJS framework. I have modified it to listen on 8000 and IP : 0.0.0.0

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/pravin-d/80c8f611b33a8002af31#file-gistfile1-txt)
See line 15 and 28

Also forgot to mention. The port was initially blocked by a firewall. However now its open (thus the tcpdump shows packet) but nodejs does not seem to get them!!

Comment: Did you run `npm install`? Did it succeed?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js try to define your addresss and your port

```
    var server = app.listen(8000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port; // put your adress here :)

    console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
    });
```

Tell me if it works :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the script. However `npm start` resolves to `node ./bin/www`  . The script essential does the same. Please check the script at [GIST](https://gist.github.com/pravin-d/80c8f611b33a8002af31#file-gistfile1-txt) .

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem solved using nginx as a reverse proxy and redirect traffic to the nodejs server. I'm not really sure what the problem still is.

PS : Should I close the question ?? Or should I wait for an explanation ?